# how to access a singleton service in program.cs which was defined in startup.cs

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have defined a singleton service within my startup.cs

```
ConfigureServices(){
   ...
   services.AddSingleton<IBenutzerLizenzDaten, BenutzerLizenzDaten>();
   ...
}
```

Now I want to access the service in my program.cs. How can I manage this?

Like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
   ...
   var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

   var benutzerLizenzDaten = host.Services.GetRequiredService<BenutzerLizenzDaten>(); // <--  Exception occurred, no service registered.
   benutzerLizenzDaten.Init();

   host.Run();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) **Call services from main** part

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `host.Services.GetRequiredService<IBenutzerLizenzDaten>();` Because of your registration `services.AddSingleton<IBenutzerLizenzDaten, BenutzerLizenzDaten>();`.